# xcode check if an NSArray exist and contains objects?

Tags: iphone, json, ipad, crash

I'm trying to get some app info using Apple API, that gives me an JSON file containing many objects.

I tried to determine the type of the app (Universal/iPhone only/iPad only) like this

```
if(([[appDetails objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"] count]>0) && ([[appDetails objectForKey:@"ipadScreenshotUrls"] count]>0))
{
    cell.appDeviceLabel.text = @"Universal";
    cell.appDeviceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.012 green:0.467 blue:0.784 alpha:1];
}

else if(([[appDetails objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"] count]==0) && ([[appDetails objectForKey:@"ipadScreenshotUrls"] count]>0)) 
{
    cell.appDeviceLabel.text = @"iPad";
    cell.appDeviceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.941 green:0.58 blue:0.016 alpha:1];        
}          
else if(([[appDetails objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"] count]>0) && ([[appDetails objectForKey:@"ipadScreenshotUrls"] count]==0))
{
    cell.appDeviceLabel.text = @"iPhone";
    cell.appDeviceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.016 green:0.459 blue:0.129 alpha:1];
}
```

Note : screenshotUrls is an array containing the images for the iphone version
ipadScreenshotUrls is the one for iPad photos.

I used the code above in my app and Apple accept it, but I get crash reports showing a problem at these lines.

May be because I'm testing the count of an array that is not found? because if the app is iphone only for exemple, the array for iPad images won't exist. Any idea how can I solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the JSON contains the value `null` for some key?

If yes, this value is converted to `NSNull` in Obj-C and any method passed to this objects results in a crash. (`NSNull` is different from `nil` in this respect.)

I usually encounter crashes with JSON in Obj-C for this reason very frequently. You should put a check in place before using any value.

```
if (value == (typecast)[NSNull null]) {
    // use the value
}
```

Note that type casting is done only to avoid compiler warning.

Comment: Yes as I said for exemple if the App is "iPhone only", the NSArray for Ipad images won't exist. So I think this is the point no? So if I understand I should test like this : if ([appDetails objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"] != (typecast)[NSNull null]) {
    // the array exist
}

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But this kind of error occurs when the JSON contains `null` as some value. If the key does not exists, the `NSDictionary` will just return `nil` and it will not cause a crash. You should actually first confirm that this is the cause. Although putting the `NSNull` check is a good practice in general when dealing with JSON.

Comment: THank you any way, just one thing, for my code listed above, is there something wrong that could make the crash? even if the NSArray don't exist can I write array.count ? thanks.

Comment: If the array does not exists, you can write array.count. But you must be sure that it is an array. For example, your code should look something like this: `id object = [appDetails objectForKey:@"screenshotUrls"];    if ([object isMemberOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {//do stuff with the object as array}`  These are small but helpful checks that make your code more robust.